# color scheme for loudness?

Tags: graphics, audio, colors, signal-processing, fft

What is the most commonly used or most appropriate coloring scheme for indicating loudness when visualizing an audio fft result, for instance in "jumping bars" audio equalizer displays, spectrograms, spectrographs, and etc.

Red for the loudest?  Blue for very quiet?  Or???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the audio apps I've shipped, it's green, yellow, red.  But that wasn't based on any standard - just a guess based on the led outputs of my stereo. :)

I think the answer is a balance between how serious you want your VU-METER to be.  Are you trying to show scientific precision of dB levels or just something that's meant to be visual eye candy as music is playing?  If the latter, you got a lot of freedom to work with, including making the increment between volume units non-linear (such that the vu-meter seems more "lively") and choosing whatever color scheme looks best.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional equalizers are green, yellow, red:

http://www.google.com/images?q=equalizer

Answer (score 1):

Typically I see green for base volume going through yellow to red for loudest. Many level meters are simply green bars until they get near the clipping level and then they jump right to red bars.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is usually green to red from quiet to loud, but generally anything starting with a cool color (such as blue) and moving to a hot color (such as red) will work.